# make error with benderrmq

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, g++

A few people have been having issues with compiling using the make command so i thought I would try here I have tried on the following OS's ubuntu 32bit and squeeze 64 bit

I clone the git project https://github.com/duckduckgo/cpp-libface/ ran the make command and I keep getting the following

```
    g++ -o lib-face src/main.cpp src/httpserver.o deps/libuv/libuv.a deps/http-parser/http_parser.o -I . -I deps -Wall  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2 -lm -lrt -pthread
In file included from src/main.cpp:21:
./include/benderrmq.hpp: In member function 'uint_t LookupTables::query_max(uint_t, uint_t, uint_t)':
./include/benderrmq.hpp:250: warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 4 has type 'size_t'
./include/benderrmq.hpp:251: warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 4 has type 'size_t'
./include/benderrmq.hpp:252: warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 4 has type 'size_t'
./include/benderrmq.hpp: In member function 'void BenderRMQ::initialize(const vui_t&)':
./include/benderrmq.hpp:353: warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'size_t'
./include/benderrmq.hpp:353: warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 4 has type 'size_t'
./include/benderrmq.hpp:354: warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'size_t'
./include/benderrmq.hpp:354: warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 4 has type 'size_t'
```

the log is longer but just pull the important part out

the file with the error is at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/duckduckgo/cpp-libface/master/include/benderrmq.hpp

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: The question was how do I amend the script to make it work @drax

Comment: All you're showing is warnings. Although they do point to a real issue here, warnings aren't errors. You specifically state in the question that you're getting an error. Are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assert macros defined here:

```
#define assert_lt(X,Y) if (!((X)<(Y))) { fprintf(stderr, "%d < %d FAILED\n", (X), (Y)); assert((X)<(Y)); }
#define assert_gt(X,Y) if (!((X)>(Y))) { fprintf(stderr, "%d > %d FAILED\n", (X), (Y)); assert((X)>(Y)); }
#define assert_le(X,Y) if (!((X)<=(Y))) { fprintf(stderr, "%d <= %d FAILED\n", (X), (Y)); assert((X)<=(Y)); }
#define assert_eq(X,Y) if (!((X)==(Y))) { fprintf(stderr, "%d == %d FAILED\n", (X), (Y)); assert((X)==(Y)); }
#define assert_ne(X,Y) if (!((X)!=(Y))) { fprintf(stderr, "%d != %d FAILED\n", (X), (Y)); assert((X)!=(Y)); }
```

https://github.com/duckduckgo/cpp-libface/blob/master/include/utils.hpp

use the `"%d"` format string in `fprintf` which is intended for integers.

But you use your macros with methods which returns a `size_t` here:

```
assert_lt(index, repr.size());
assert_lt(l, repr[0].size() + 1);
assert_lt(u, repr[0][0].size());
```

and here:

```
assert_eq(levels.size(), euler.size());
assert_eq(levels.size(), rev_mapping.size());
```

https://github.com/duckduckgo/cpp-libface/blob/master/include/benderrmq.hpp

So you can either create other macros which uses `"%zu"` or you cast the result of the `size`methods to a signed integer (if you know there will most likely be no overflow problem).

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard warning of the printf. Good point to start is:

```
man 3 printf
```

Basically the solution is this:

```
std::size_t a0 = 1234;
printf("%zu\n", a0);
```

instead of:

```
std::size_t a0 = 1234;
printf("%d\n", a0);
```